# How to handle null value?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, null, object-reference

I am writing one LINQ to select data from entity. I have list of data with different attributes. One of the attribute could be null. so when it get null it giving me an below error

Error:

```
Object reference not set to instance of an object
```

Here is LINQ code:

```
var maxName = NameLookup.Select(c => c.DESC.Length).Max()
```

If DESC has null value than it should be also acceptable. I mean to say i want to handle if it contains null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var maxName = NameLookup.Select(c => (c.DESC != null) ? c.DESC.Length : 0).Max()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var  maxName = NameLookup.Max(c => c.DESC!= null ? c.DESC.Length : 0);
```